# MSAnimationStart event doesn't work on IE10

Tags: javascript, events, animation, internet-explorer-10

Please check [this animationstart event test](http://jsfiddle.net/IanY/rhsWL/). It works on newer versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

However, it doesn't work on the latest version of IE10 on Win8 (on virtual machine). I had tested the CSS3 animation support in the IE10 by using it to browse websites which have CSS3 animation effects and all effects work.

Does IE10 have any problem firing the javascript `MSAnimationStart` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. It turns out that IE10 cannot handle CSS `clip` property correctly. [The test](http://jsfiddle.net/IanY/rhsWL/10/) has been updated to use `opacity` instead of `clip`.

Thanks to [SitePoint's article](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/).